# systemd service failed ,

Tags: linux, systemd, rhel

```
● eip.service - making eip connection up
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/eip.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-08-25 21:21:24 CDT; 7min ago
  Process: 244843 ExecStart=/home/svceip/scripts/startstop/start_eip (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 244843 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Aug 25 21:21:24 systemd[1]: Started making eip connection up.
Aug 25 21:21:24 systemd[1]: eip.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Aug 25 21:21:24 systemd[1]: eip.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

can anyone provide hint to resolve this issue?

Comment: The error message (code=exited, status=203/EXEC) is often seen when the script itself or its interpreter cannot be executed.

It could have these reasons:

wrong path to script (e.g. /home/py/ReadPressure2AndPostToMqtt.py)
script not executable
no shebang (first line)
wrong path in shebang (e.g. /bin/python3)
internal files in your script might be missing access permissions.

Also, do show the journalctl output for that service.

Comment: See what  "journalctl -b -u eip.service" says.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on @Grace Thompson's comment:

[`man systemd.exec`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Process%20Exit%20Codes) describes exit code 203 as:

> The actual process execution failed (specifically, the execve(2) system call). Most likely this is caused by a missing or non-accessible executable file.

In your case, you need to ensure `/home/svceip/scripts/startstop/start_eip`:

1. Exists.  If not put your binary/script there.
2. Is executable (`ls -l /home/svceip/scripts/startstop/start_eip` shows `-rwxr-xr-x`).  If not, use `chmod +x /home/svceip/scripts/startstop/start_eip`.
3. Is an executable.  If you use `file /home/svceip/scripts/startstop/start_eip`, then it should show `ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable` or some variation starting with `ELF`.  If it shows `ASCII text executable`, then the first line needs a shebang.  In that case, ensure the first line contains `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/python3` or whatever is needed to run that script.

Comment: I see a `rhel` tag, and I think I remember that SELinux does not like systemd reaching into a user’s home directory when executing programs.  Also, I think ProtectHome=yes will prevent systemd services from seeing in homesites.  Best to just move the executables elsewhere.